# Adjusting date differences

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

The following script is getting the selected day plus 59 days after, I need help to amend it to 30 days before and after (30 days before the selected day + selected day + 30 days after the selected day).

```
<script lang="javascript">
    function setOptions(selected_holiday) 
    { 
    sh = new Date();
    aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    sh_year = selected_holiday.substr(0, 4) ;
    sh_month = selected_holiday.substr(4, 2) - 0;
    sh_day = selected_holiday.substr(6, 2) ;
    sh.setFullYear(sh_year,sh_month-1,sh_day);
    sh.setTime(sh.getTime()+aDay);

    sh_max = new Date(sh.getTime()+(59*aDay)+aDay);
    var defoff_date = document.deferform.defoff_date; 
    defoff_date.options.length = 0; 

    for (i=sh.getTime();i<sh_max;i+=aDay) {
    date = new Date(i);
    year = date.getYear();
    slash = "/";
    if (year < 1900) year += 1900;
    strDay = "0"+ date.getDate();
    strDay =strDay.substr(strDay.length-2,2);
    strMonth = "0"+ (date.getMonth()+1);
    strMonth = strMonth.substr(strMonth.length-2,2);
    strDate = "" + strMonth + slash + strDay + slash + year;
    defoff_date.options[defoff_date.options.length] = new Option(strDate); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the line that does the calculation:

```
sh_max = new Date(sh.getTime()+(59*aDay)+aDay);
```

After this, `sh` and `sh_max` are "now" and "sixty days after now".

If you change it to

```
sh_min = new Date(sh.getTime()-30*aDay);
sh_max = new Date(sh.getTime()+30*aDay+aDay);
```

then `sh_min` and `sh_max` will be "thirty days before now" and "thirty one days after now". You'd also change the loop to reflect the new variable name:

```
for (i=sh_min.getTime();i<sh_max;i+=aDay) {
```

Comment: You can also use `sh_min = new Date(+sh - 30*aDay);` to save a bit of typing. :-)